# Saving in session - Liferay Portlets

Tags: java, session, liferay, liferay-6, portlet

I have a search page which populates search results.

I can redirect to other pages from search screen.

When a user wants to return to the search screen, I want to show the same search results.

The obvious option which rings is saving in session. Is that a good design?

Is it possible to store such amount of data in session in liferay? How? Any pointers are much appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

Is it possible? Yes. *Just* allocate enough memory for the session size times number of concurrent users. Of course, calculate first if this is feasible. Optimize if necessary. Also, keep in mind that two concurrent searches in separate tabs that are open concurrently could easily interfere with each other.

My recommendation would be to first investigate if you can't store just the search terms and maybe the results page and execute the search again when/if required. Or just keep track of all of the previous searches of a user. This way you don't even need it in the session, but can store it in the database, keyed by the userid (for logged in users) or sessionid (for anonymous users)